# SharePoint Online Custom List Word-Wrap Titles

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, title-column

I am using SharePoint Online and have a custom list in the Modern Experience that has long titles for a few columns. With no luck I have been searching for a solution to have Word-Wraping on the title fields.

I have looked into JSON formatting and so far all of the articles talk about the data fields and not the title headers.

If this was the old SharePoint, I would write CSS in a CEWP and it would be a done deal, but this doesn't appear to be an option anymore in the Modern Experience.

Any tips or solutions to getting long title names in a custom list on SharePoint Online (Modern Experience) to do a Word-Wrap?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the official document below, there is not a method to substring the text.

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

As a workaround, we can use the JSON formatting below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style":{
        "white-space":"nowrap"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @LZ_MSFT.

Comment: Has anyone tapped into the styles used for headers that would allow a double line?  
I have the "SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection" installed which allows me to override CSS.  I know this is not recommended by Microsoft, but it is helpful as long as I realize that this could change at any time.

Answer (score 1):

@LZ_MSFT
Isn't that the code for NOT Wrapping column text? It looks like it is. Thus the **code TO wrap column text** would look like what I show below. Copy the code below and paste it in the **Column Formatting** text box for a column --> Click **Save** --> Go back to the list and hover over the column breaks --> Adjust the column width as desired --> Click dropdown arrow for that view --> Select **Save view as** --> Click **Save**

Start of JSON code is below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style":{
        "white-space":"wrap"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a lead for this.  Is this for the column headers?  I tried this and didn't seem to help.

Comment: Does nothing for me, either.